# how to find all triples $(c_1, c_2, c_3)?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}
\end{bmatrix}
$$  be   a real matrices  . let $c_1 , c_2, $and$   c_3 $ be  the scalars

$$
c_1 = det(
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{12}&a_{13}\\ a_{22}&a_{23}
\end{bmatrix})
$$      $$
c_2 = det(
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{13}&a_{11}\\ a_{23}&a_{21}
\end{bmatrix})
$$ 
  $$
c_3 = det(
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}
\end{bmatrix})
$$

Find all triples $(c_1, c_2, c_3) $so that $rank A = 2$

this is the orginal question

[image]

i was looking this problem at book linear algebra by Kennneth hoffman and Ray kunze (2 edition pearson publisher) page no : 149 Q.10

It is given that  $rank(A) = 2$ if and only if ($c_1,c_2, c_3$) $\neq 0$

here  i don't know how can i find all the triples $(c_1, c_2, c_3) $so that $rank A = 2$

i would be thankful  if someone help me,,,,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that to have rank=2 we need two column linearly independent; the third can be

1. independent from each one of the others or
2. can be a multiple of one of them

Comment: $$
c_1 = det(
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\ 1&0
\end{bmatrix})
$$      $$
c_2 = det(
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\ 0&2
\end{bmatrix})
$$ 
  $$
c_3 = det(
\begin{bmatrix}
3&0\\ 0&3
\end{bmatrix})
$$       Is  its correct ???? @ gimusi..pliz reply me

Comment: @Nehagupta In the first case we obtain $c_1,c_2,c_3 \neq 0$ in the second we obtain triple with one zero $(c_1,c_2,0),(c_1,0,c_3),(0,c_2,c_1) $ if the third is $\neq0$ and  triple with two zeros $(c_1,0,0),(0,0,c_3),(0,c_2,0) $ if the third is $=0$.

Comment: thanks u @ gimusi